# python parameter_$i in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, parameters

I would like to assign some value in incremental parameter name by for loop but there are some error to recognize the parameter name as below.

```
for i in range(1,4):
    print i
    Name_i = h5py.File(filename_BS_i, "r")
```

What I expect,

1st for loop
Name_1 = h5py.File(filename_1, "r")

2nd for loop
Name_2 = h5py.File(filename_2, "r")
.
.

Do you have any idea.?

I know, it works if I change parameter i_Name instead of Name_i

Thanks!

Comment: `Format String`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a dictionary. e.g.

`Names = {}
for i in range(1,4):
    Names[i] = h5py.File(filename_BS_ + str(i), "r")`

Comment: This will store all your files in a dictionary, which can be indexed by the corresponding integer.

Comment: Thanks! it's working!